# How to increase the maximum allowed upload filesize for Moodle

Tags: moodle, scorm, scorm1.2

I've tried all of the suggestions that I've found and haven't succeeded in eliminating the error message:

```
The page at [ip address] says:
[filename] is too large to upload
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.1 server and Moodle 2.3.1+.  As others have suggested, I modified
`/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` adding 
`LimitRequestBody 0` so that there is no limit on the maximum size of uploads.

I also modified `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` setting:

```
post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
max_execution_time = 300
```

Those changes actually had an effect on Moodle and caused it to list larger upload limits in the site security policies and the course settings.  Prior to revising php.ini the maximums were 2MB. And so, I set each of those limits to 1GB.

```
http://[ip address]/moodle/admin/settings.php?section=sitepolicies
http://[ip address]/moodle/admin/settings.php?section=coursesettings
```

And still I get the error message that the file I'm trying to upload is too large.  It is only 30MB.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you reload your web-server instance?
2. What about [memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) directive?
3. Did you try to search any .htaccess file, that might override your settings?

However, your question is related to the [PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size) issue

---

Moodle docs:

- [How do the limits on uploaded files work?](http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Administration_FAQ#How_do_the_limits_on_uploaded_files_work.3F)
- [File upload size](http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/File_upload_size)

To see your actual php settings, you can look at:
`http://[path to moodle]/admin/phpinfo.php` and `http://[path to moodle]/admin/environment.php`

Comment: yes, yes and yes :)  I read about memory_limit, and didn't see how it should effect uploads, but tried it anyway.  Couldn't find any other .htaccess files.  Changing the php settings did effect the Moodle interface; however, Moodle (assumedly) is still throwing the error even when it is set to allow 1GB uploads.